# How do I restore triple tap to emulate the middle click?

Tags: xorg, 11.10, gnome, touchpad, x11

I've upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10 but the ability to tap with three fingers on the touchpad to achieve a middle mouse click has disappeared. When a mouse is plugged in the middle button click works exactly as expected.

I've tried similar approaches to: [Swapping the double and triple finger tap actions on trackpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58735/swapping-the-double-and-triple-finger-tap-actions-on-trackpad) and using `$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse middle-button-enabled true` but still nothing works.

I'm using an asus ul-30a which is typically well supported under linux. I'm using gnome-shell but the problem also occurs when using unity.

Could anyone advise how to fix the triple tap please?

***EDIT:*** *I've also tried installing the kde package synaptiks and setting the button functions and this also has no effect*

Comment: See bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/utouch/+bug/754000

Comment: Also see [bug 840509](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/840509)

Comment: I managed to make the config persistent by placing the proper configuration in a file called `70-synaptics.conf` and placing it in the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` directory. And, yes my laptop has a Synaptics touchpad. I have [linked the conf file](https://gist.github.com/sivaraam/410f4bf672c4c757206d1bd8bfbcfc68) that I use for reference. This works fine for me on a laptop running lubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 5):

Using gnome-shell on 12.04 (precise), I'm able to restore triple tap middle click support by running the following:

```
synclient TapButton3=2
```

This command tells the Synaptic driver to make a triple tap gesture (`TapButton3`) send a middle click (mouse button 2) event.

However, I'm not sure how to best make this change persistent.  I could put it in a script [as suggested by this blog post](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2011/11/06/persistent-touchpad-configuration-in-ubuntu-11-10/), but that approach seems awkward to me.  There's got to be a better way.

Comment: Did you find a better solution to make this persistent? same problem here: [Simulate a middle-click on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro Synaptics touchpad](http://askubuntu.com/q/485863)

Comment: I solved it as a workaround by [executing the command 40 seconds after the desktop is booted](http://askubuntu.com/a/518506)

Answer (score 4):

Just found an amazing thing:

Taping on the top right corner of the touchpad is like clicking the middle mouse button.
I know it's not the same as the triple click and position accuracy is needed :( but it's the closest I could find to triple click.

BTW, clicking on the lower right corner is like clicking the the right mouse button.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://grepmonster.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/ubuntu-11-10-middle-mouse-button-emulation/) shows how to restore middle mouse button emulation by simultaneously clicking with both buttons.

Comment: I can already do this without any changes and that only works in 11.04 not 11.10.

Comment: oh. no other ideas :(

Answer (score 0):

synclient ClickFinger3=3

Found it [here](https://plus.google.com/+StevenHolms/posts/EBgngfVQU4f).