# Middle click with a three finger touchpad tap on 11.10, How can I restore this?

Tags: mouse, touchpad

Synaptic touchpads used to support a three finger tap for middle clicking in Ubuntu 10.10 (same as clicking the scroll wheel on a mouse.)

This critical functionality is broken in Ubuntu 11.10

How can I restore middle clicking on a touchpad?

Comment: Odd, I never had this functionality with my two Synaptic touchpads...

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/64158/how-do-i-restore-triple-tap-to-emulate-the-middle-click

Comment: See and vote for the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/utouch/+bug/754000

Comment: The problem still exists in 14.04 but seemingly not on all devices. I still have this on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro. The bug url changed: [bug 754000](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/754000) which was moved to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/971783

Answer (score 5):

You could use a commandline programme called "synclient", which should be already on your system.

```
synclient Tapbutton3=2
```

where "Tapbutton3" means a Two-Finger Tap, and the 2 is for middle click.

This method only works until restart (or some other mousesettings-program overrides it). To get this functionality permanently, put this in **/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf** before "EndSection"

```
Option "TapButton3" "2"
```

Comment: Commandline works fine, but only till log out, as you say. But editing 50-synaptics.conf doesn't anything. Shell it on 12.04? The Option "Ignore" should be "on" then? Is it important: spaces, tabs, little/great letters?

Comment: try adding Option "SHMConfig" "on" after the 'ignore' option and restart

Comment: Fixed a typo -- should read "TapButton". However, I just tried changing some settings on my new 12.04 xubuntu install -> 50-synaptics does nothing :(

Comment: @marto At the top of `50-synaptics.conf` there is a note saying not to edit it- copy it into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` (you'll probably have to make the directory yourself). Once you do this, edit the copied file.

Comment: Can you help me how to [Simulate a middle-click on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro Synaptics touchpad](http://askubuntu.com/q/485863) too?

Answer (score 4):

Just found an amazing thing:
Taping on the top right corner of the touchpad is like clicking the middle mouse button.
I know it's not the same as the triple click and position accuracy is needed :( but it's the closest I could find to triple click.

BTW, clicking on the lower right corner is like clicking the the right mouse button.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/106444/13330

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the ubuntu patches against xserver-xorg-input-synaptics package.

The solution to the problem is simple - just replace the ubuntu-provided package with one without those patches.

Here's how:

Download the appropriate Debian package from this site (choose your architecture, either i386 or amd64):

http://packages.debian.org/squeeze-backports/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

Then remove the original package from your system and replace it with the one downloaded.
Reboot the system and 3-finger tapping should be working again.

Comment: Has anyone tried this? The person answering the question has too little score to take the risk.

Comment: Whatever "too little score to take the risk" is supposed to mean, I edited the post to add the correct package link. And yes, it works.