# Simulate a middle-click on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro Synaptics touchpad

Tags: mouse, touchpad, lenovo

I Am writing a Guide How to install [Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367963/ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-2-pro?lq=1)

To get a middle Mousebutton, I tried this:

I edited the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`. 
There I edited the "touchpad catchall" section, so it will look like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    # This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
    # enabled by default. See the following link for details:
    # http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"

    Option "FingerLow"              "46"
    Option "FingerHigh"             "46"
    Option "ClickFinger1"           "1"
    Option "ClickFinger2"           "2"
    Option "ClickFinger3"           "3"
    Option "TapButton1"             "1"
    Option "TapButton2"             "2"
    Option "TapButton3"             "3"
    Option "AreaBottomEdge"         "85%"
    Option "SoftButtonAreas"        "60% 0 85% 0 40% 60% 85% 0" # Btn2 LRTB - Btn3 LRTB
    Option "EmulateMidButtonTime"   "75"
EndSection
```

*(source: http://memobadz.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/lenovo-yoga-pro-2-on-ubuntu/ )*

But this didn't enable a simulated **Middle click** as mentioned in *memobadz' wordpress Blog* (although it still helped a lot in other aspects).

### How do I simulate a Middle mouse-button by **tapping three Fingers**?

I couldn't manage it with that help so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is what I have in the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` and works as intended.

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "TapButton2" "3"
    Option "TapButton3" "2"
EndSection
```

Alternatively, you can create a script as described in

[Execute a command 20 seconds after the desktop is booted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518503/execute-a-command-20-seconds-after-the-desktop-is-booted/518506#518506)

or include the commands below in `$HOME/.xprofile`

```
sleep 20
synclient TapButton2=3
synclient TapButton3=2
```

Comment: So you swapped "TapButton2" and 3. Cool that seems to help a bit: now I can **tap and then click with two fingers** to simulate a middle mouse click. Can you explain, why this helps? And isn't there a solution to simulate it with a **tripple-finger-tap**?

Comment: The way I use it is, I highlight a link or some text and paste it using 3-finger tap.
I hope it helps.

Comment: @rubo77 Did you actually test this? The middle mouse button is usually considered number 2, at least in programs I've worked with.

Comment: Yes, but it is hard to tell if it changes anything. At least it does not enable tree finger tap

Comment: I found the soution: [How do I restore triple tap to emulate the middle click?](http://askubuntu.com/a/126707) - simply type on the console: `synclient TapButton3=2` - only stays the question how to make it permanent. I tried to put it into /etc/local.rc` and I tried to put it into the startup programs, but it is strange: right after boot, the three finger tap works, but after some seconds it seems to be resetted

Comment: The workaround is to [execute a command 20 seconds after the desktop is booted](http://askubuntu.com/a/518506), But it is strange, cause If I don't call `synclient TapButton3=2` the value for TapButton3 is set back to 0 a few seconds after the desktop is booted, the same time when the global 2x zoom effect is applied to all windows: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gconf/+bug/1322026

Comment: Do you want me to add the link ?

Comment: Instead of having a script, you can put the commands also in your .xprofile. Can you check if that works too ?

Comment: I will try that  tomorrow

Comment: Adding it like this in my `.xprofile` doesn't work! instead it will have a delay of 20 seconds until the desktop will show and the middle button still doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change anything to middle-click on the touchpad in Ubuntu -- you can just tap the upper-right corner per this answer from 2012 (still true now in Ubuntu derivative Linux Mint 18): https://askubuntu.com/a/141460

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Uuntu 16.04. can you add your touchpad settings here please? I guess it is also defined in the file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf