# 3-finger tap getting prematurely grabbed

Tags: 11.10, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics, gestures

Recently I upgraded from Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.04. By default 2-finger tap was set to right click and 3-finger tap (3FT) to middle click (button 3). 2-finger tap works fine when I set tap-action to x x x x 1 3 2 or x x x x 1 2 3, meaning that, it's not the middle click event that is being grabbed but the 3FT, before it even gets translated to an event defined by tap-action. Proof that 3FT is in fact detected is that whenever I 3FT inside an unmaximized window I get this:
[image: screenshot].

I followed instructions from the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1862290&page=2#14) but my system got really unstable for an unknown reason: from sporadic log-offs to frozen screens to tap-click not working at login. I reinstalled 11.10 because of it and now I'm posting this.

Any one can see through this problem?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to clarify what the initial situation is/was, and what you now want instead of it?

Comment: could u please elaborate what do you mean by "initial situation". since this is a default feature you are dished out, after a fresh installation of 11.10. And i want it disabled/undone to enable 3FT to generate an event-which it, right now, is kept from doing

Comment: For example, could you create the equivalent of a table where we would see what 2FT and 3FT do by default and in another column what you want them to do?

Comment: the pic in my original post states the default i.e. 2FT=left-click and 3FT=middle-click and thats what i want it do. tap-action= 2 3 0 0 1 3 2

Comment: So you reinstalled 11.10 and you want your computer to have the default gestures, but you don't have them anymore? Is that correct? I am not sure I get what "xxxx132" means.

Comment: no no no!!! READ the last part of my question.
paraphrased: i wanted 3FT=middle-click which it wasn't producing so i followed that link (the 2nd one). It worked but then my system got really unstable blah blah blah started happening. so i reinstalled 11.10. and i'm not following the 2nd link again and i want 3FT=middle click
in xxxx123, "x" means a don't care condition. As in, im not concerned with what value it takes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure if this will be helpful to you, but you can try to adapt the instructions of this question: [Swapping the double and triple finger tap actions on trackpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58735/swapping-the-double-and-triple-finger-tap-actions-on-trackpad). I hope it helps.

Comment: been there done that.
the problem is much more abstruse